# LibCurl3 / Libcurl4 in 18.04

Tags: 18.04

Libcurl 4 installation is working for 18.04. We require Libcurl3 to work on Ubuntu 18.04. Since this isn't backward compatible. We want to how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Install it: `sudo apt-get install libcurl3`

Comment: If you need to have both at the same time, try this: https://dev.to/jake/using-libcurl3-and-libcurl4-on-ubuntu-1804-bionic-184g